# Show external url content inside Angular component

Tags: angular

I need to add to my existing component HTML data from an external url.
I don't want to be redirected to the url site, just to present the content on my existing component.

I thought to download the html content and use [innerHTML] tag on the parent component.
I'm having problems downloading the HTML content, is there a working sample that achieves that and does this is the correct approach?

Comment: you can try using `<iframe>` to embed another document within the current HTML document

Comment: this is not possible, there is "same origin" header value on the server.